# Hamilton cycles in Cayley graphs: between Rapaport-Strasser and Fleischner

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, hamiltonian-graphs

A well-known question of Rapaport-Strasser asks whether every finite connected Cayley graph has a Hamilton cycle. Fleischner's Theorem implies that if $S$ is the generating set of such a Cayley graph $Cay(G,S)$, then by adding at most $2|S|^2$ further generators (of the form $\{st \mid s,t\in S\}$), we can obtain a hamiltonian supergraph $Cay(G,S')$.

**Question**: What is the smallest $k(n)$ for which you can prove that for every finite connected Cayley graph $Cay(G,S)$ with $|S|=n$, there is a set $T$ of at most $k(n)$ elements of $G$, such that $Cay(G,S \cup T)$ is hamiltonian?

Conjecturally, $k(n)=0$, but any improvement over Fleischner's $k(n)\leq 2n^2$ would be nice.

Comment: For the sake of historical justice. The problem about the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle has been known for a very long time. See e.g. [here](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/hamiltonian_paths_and_cycles_in_vertex_transitive_graphs).